# Excel IF OR Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am having trouble determining the correct way to calculate a final rank order for four categories. Each of the four metrics make up a higher group. A Top 10 of each category is applied to the respective product to risk analysis.

CURRENT LOGIC - Assignment of 25% max per category.

```
Columns - Y4      
Parts    
0.25     
25    


=IF(L9=1,$Y$4,IF(L9=2,$Y$4*0.9, IF(L9=3,$Y$4*0.8, IF(L9=4,$Y$4*0.7, IF(L9=5,$Y$4*0.6, IF(L9=6,$Y$4*0.5, IF(L9=7,$Y$4*0.4, IF(L9=8,$Y$4*0.3, IF(L9=9,$Y$4*0.2, IF(L9=10,$Y$4*0.1,0))))))))))
```

DESIRED...

I would like to use a statement to determine three criteria in order to apply a score (1=100, 2=90, 3=80, etc..).

1. SUM the rank positions of each of the four categories-apply product rank ascending (not including NULL since it's not in the Top 10)
2. IF a product is identified in more than one metric-apply a significant contribution weight of (*.75),
3. IF a product has the number 1 rank in any of the four metrics-apply a score of (100).

Data - **UPDATED EXAMPLE**

```
(Product)    Parts  Labor      Overhead      External       Final Score
"XYZ"        3           1      7             7             100
"ABC"        NULL           6          NULL          2              100
"LMN"        4              NULL       NULL          NULL           70
```

This is way beyond my capability. ANY assistance is appreciated greatly!!!

Jim

I figured this is a good start and I can alter the weight as needed to reflect the reality of the situation.

```
 =AVERAGE(G28:I28)+SUM(G28:I28)*0.25
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to put a cap on the score of no more than 100 points.

Comment: can you explain point 2 more clearly? Also the highest a score can be is 100 correct?

Comment: Sure. I don't think I provided all of the examples needed, sorry about that. Most of the products are single category hit list drivers. Say product "LMN" only had one criteria within the top 10, Parts, but each of the other 3 where NULL. I would like to add additional emphasis on those making more than one category to elevate the visibility.

Comment: okay. that helps. one more question - what would the final results in your example be? just so it's clear what you expect. once I know that, I can write the formula.

Comment: Sorry about that.. yes, that was difficult.

Comment: why is "ABC" = 100? And how is "LMN" = 70? Sorry, but your formula and your results do not match. I understand "XYZ" because it has a 1 in Labor. Is "ABC" = 100 because a `2` is worth 80 points and a `6` is worth 4 points, but you cap it 100?

Comment: LMN =70 using the 1=100, 2=90, 3=80, 4=70 point assignment. ABC is where I'm running into the challenge of determining if a product has risk in more than one category. This is where I used the formula above in the problem (at the end) to apply a weight to elevate the importance since it has two significant drivers rather than using the highest rank, (in this example it is 2, which would be 90 points).

Comment: it's just not really clear what you are trying to achieve. If you are capping at 100 anyway, a weight for 2 or more will not matter. perhaps conditional formatting can show you where you have more than 1 factor?

Comment: Yes, 1 is the highest risk. Basically pivot on each category (Costs, Occurrences, etc.) and sort descending to get the top 10 contributors, ranking 1-10. Each are risks out of the 10,000 or so. #1 is the big focus usually but I am trying to show that just because something isn't #1, it can be just as important since it's affecting multiple areas.

Comment: This factor is one of 8 other metrics being plugged into a combined threat to achieve an enterprise view of all factors. One view, many lenses. The reason for 100 cap is to keep the various factors on a level playing field.... not to give financials more weight than other areas, that are just as important in other's perceptions and interests.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unclear of what exactly you are attempting and if this will work, but how about this simple matrix using an array formula and some conditional formatting.

[image]

Array Formula in F2 (make sure to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when exiting formula edit mode)

```
=MIN(100,SUM(IF(B2:E2<>"NULL",CHOOSE(B2:E2,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10))))
```

Conditional Formatting defined as shown below.

- Red = 100 value where it comes from a `1`
- Yellow = 100 value where it comes from more than 1 factor, but without a 1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's does make sense in my head, I'm sure if that's a good thing or not. I'll keep this in my playbook and keep trying to break excel. I truly appreciate your time and effort on this, Scott.